# Complex query with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The 'complex'-part of the title might be subjective, but for me, it is rather complex.

I have a table called `Contracts (C)` and `FinancialYears (FY)`. A contract will have multiple financial years (one per year), created automatically, if a specific status is met (for example, cancelled contracts won't get new financial year records, but approved contracts will). It's the FY that is having a specific status each years. For example:

```
--------------------FinancialYears-------------------
ContractID: 1          | 1          | 1
StatusID:   2          | 3          | 5
dStart:     01-01-2012 | 01-01-2013 | 01-01-2014
dEnd:       31-12-2012 | 31-12-2013 | 31-12-2014
Year:       2012       | 2013       | 2014
-----------------------------------------------------
(For example: StatusID (2, 3, 5), (Proposed, Approved, Cancelled))
```

Now assume a user wants to find out how many contracts are approved at this point of time, then the query should be looking at the most recent financial year of the contract, and that's what I'm having a hard time with.

I have to write a query that does the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contracts C
INNER JOIN FinancialYears FY ON FY.ContractID = C.ContractID
WHERE StatusID = X AND (dStart < GETDATE() AND dEnd > GETDATE()) 
// This would search on the financial year of the contract which has its valid
period in-between today.
```

But since a, for example, cancelled contract will not have a new financial year in the next year, I would never be able to query today on a cancelled contract of 2014, so I need to adjust the following condition to the query somehow:

```
// IF (dStart < GETDATE() AND dEnd > GETDATE()) RETURNS 0, THEN DO INSTEAD:
SELECT TOP 1 
//
WHERE (dEnd < GETDATE) 
ORDER BY ENDDATE DESC
// With other words: if there is no ongoing financial year between the given time interval,
then select the most recent financial year in the past.
```

Could anyone help me out here?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide expected result from your test data?

Comment: If you want always the latest, isn't it just top 1 ContractID from FinancialYears where dStart < GETDATE() order by dEnd desc?

Comment: @Giorgi I'm expecting to get a contract back with a status which is the most recent status. So instead of having 4 records saying 2012-2013-2014-2015 are approved contracts for ContractID 2, I want it to say in 1 record: 2015 approved contract for ContractID 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick mock-up:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contracts C
cross apply (
select top 1 ContractID 
from FinancialYears where dStart < GETDATE() 
order by dEnd desc
) F on C.ConractID = F.ContractID
```

But you'll probably need some extra criteria to find all of the Contracts, for example customer code or something.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to filter the contracts where the current date falls between the start and end date of contracts that are approved if I'm not mistaken.

### [Here's a demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c31f/1)

**MS SQL Server Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE FinancialYearContracts
    ([ContractID] int, [StatusID] int, [dStart] datetime, [dEnd] datetime, [Year] int)
;

INSERT INTO FinancialYearContracts
    ([ContractID], [StatusID], [dStart], [dEnd], [Year])
VALUES
    (1, 2, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-12-31 00:00:00', 2012),
    (1, 3, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', '2013-12-31 00:00:00', 2013),
    (1, 5, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-12-31 00:00:00', 2014),
    (2, 2, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', '2013-12-31 00:00:00', 2013),
    (2, 3, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-12-31 00:00:00', 2014),
    (2, 3, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 2015),
    (3, 2, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-12-31 00:00:00', 2014),
    (3, 3, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 2015),
    (4, 2, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-12-31 00:00:00', 2014),
    (5, 2, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', '2013-12-31 00:00:00', 2013),
    (5, 3, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-12-31 00:00:00', 2014),
    (5, 3, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 2015),
    (6, 2, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', '2013-12-31 00:00:00', 2012),
    (6, 3, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-12-31 00:00:00', 2013),
    (6, 5, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 2014)
;
```

**Query to generate results**:

```
declare @DateFilter as datetime = GETDATE()
declare @Status as int = 3


SELECT * 
FROM FinancialYearContracts
WHERE @DateFilter BETWEEN dStart AND dEnd AND StatusID = @Status
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c31f/1/0)**:

```
| CONTRACTID | STATUSID |                         DSTART |                            DEND | YEAR |
|------------|----------|--------------------------------|---------------------------------|------|
|          2 |        3 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | December, 31 2015 00:00:00+0000 | 2015 |
|          3 |        3 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | December, 31 2015 00:00:00+0000 | 2015 |
|          5 |        3 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | December, 31 2015 00:00:00+0000 | 2015 |
```

This shows contracts that are currently in the approved status based on the sample data I put together.

Comment: @IvanM i'm not sure looking at your comments this is what you're after now, please let me know and I will delete the answer if this is the case.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. Yes, this is the good case, where all contracts have a financial year record every year. But if one contract is missing a financial year because it's expired or something, then I really need to go for the 2nd criteria... Where JamesZ got a good point. It's a lot simpler than I thought. Still appreciate the help and the clear elaboration! Thank you!

Comment: this query is simply working off today's date, so if a contract doesn't have a record in the table where the date/status criteria is met it won't be displayed, is that not what you want?

Comment: If it does have no record, then yes. But say a contract had been in execution from 2000 till end 2013, then cancelled in 2014. 2015 will not have an automatic created year record due to the cancelled status, so when an employee would want to query on all the cancelled contracts, it would return nothing - and it should return the one that was cancelled in 2014